# Install specific branch from github using Npm

Tags: github, npm-install

I would like to install bootstrap-loader from github in my project using npm

Currently they are maintaining two version of this project which are comaptible with webpack version 1 and 2.

I would like to install version [1](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/tree/v1). What npm command I should use to install this?

I tried using below one but it is not working.

```
npm install git://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader.git[#v1] --Save
```

Answer (score 443, accepted):

There are extra square brackets in the command you tried.

To install the latest version from the `brach-name` branch, you can use:

```
npm install "https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader.git#branch-name" --save
```

Comment: if we had to attach the specific version. then how would it be along with branch?

Comment: @Md_ZubairAhmed The branch name in his example just happened to be named "v1" -- it could be named something else like "my-branch", and behave the same way.

Comment: If you want to install a specific comit, you can do: `npm install https://github.com/username/package#3d0a21cc` Where `3d0a21cc` are the first eight characters of the commit hash. I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51560215/6086226)

Comment: For info, github has removed the [git:// procotol](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#no-more-unauthenticated-git) so you cannot use this method anymore. You should omit the protocol and let npm detect that it is a github repository (see the answer just below : `npm install username/repo#branchName --save`)

Comment: Any way to do this with a private git repo?

Answer (score 129):

**npm:** `npm install username/repo#branchName --save`

**yarn:** `yarn add username/repo#branchName`

**e.g.** `npm i betimer/rtc-attach#master --save` (my username is betimer)

```
// this will appear in your package.json:
"rtc-attach": "github:betimer/rtc-attach#master"
```

One thing I also want to mention: it's not a good idea to check in the package.json for the build server auto pull the change. Instead, put the npm i (first command) into the build command, and let server just install and replace the package.

One more note, if the package.json private is set to true, may impact sometimes.

Comment: Any chance you could do this for a package within a monorepo?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Yes, you can do `npm install <folder>`

Comment: Does not work: npm i facebook/https://github.com/facebook/jest.git#master --save. Or this: npm i facebook/git@github.com:facebook/jest.git#master --save. Does not work either

Comment: @Donato Please follow the pattern in the example

Comment: @Xin it doesn't work: npm i facebook/jest#master --save  ERR! Can't install github:facebook/jest#b5c7092687a265e3f4f2ba6f9787e47e8c6b9d5e: Missing package name

Comment: It works on other packages, which I have just tried. meaning their should be some setting wrong in that package

Comment: @Xin this is the most popular JavaScript Testing Framework. This is not just a random package.

Comment: it may be because of package private in package.json or other settings, you can fork that repo, and remove all doubtable settings, then connect to your branch. That's some of my thought. @Donato

Answer (score 45):

you can give git pattern as version, yarn and npm are clever enough to resolve from a git repo.

```
yarn add any-package@user-name/repo-name#branch-name
```

or for npm

```
npm install --save any-package@user-name/repo-name#branch-name
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Try the following: npm i jest@facebook/git@github.com:facebook/jest.git#master

Answer (score 16):

Another approach would be to add the following line to `package.json` dependencies:

```
"package-name": "user/repo#branch"
```

For example:

```
"dependencies": {
    ... other dependencies ...

    "react-native": "facebook/react-native#master"
}
```

And then do `npm install` or `yarn install`

Answer (score 10):

I'm using SSH to authenticate my GitHub account and have a couple dependencies in my project installed as follows:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "<dependency name>": "git+ssh://git@github.com/<github username>/<repository name>.git#<release version | branch>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Just a comment this is the way I added using npm i. (notice the *:* instead of */* between github.com and the user name)
*npm i git+ssh://git@github.com:<github username>/<repository name>.git#<release version | branch>*

Answer (score 5):

Had to put the url in quotes for it work

```
npm install "https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader.git#v1" --save
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried suggested answers, but got it working only with this prefix approach:

```
npm i github:user/repo.git#version --save -D
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 3):

Only solution working for me:

```
$ npm i https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/tarball/{BRANCH} --save
```

as explained [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/install-npm-packages-from-gitgithub).

Answer (score -1):

Both below versions work for me as of beginning of 2023:

```
npm i "github:shakacode#bootstrap-loader"

npm i "https://github.com/shakacode/tree/bootstrap-loader/"
```

Answer (score -6):

The Doc of the npm defines that only tag/version can be specified after repo_url.

Here is the Doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: The documents clearly state that `#commitish` is allowed for `npm install <git remote url>`