# How Do I Install Specific Git Branch Using NPM?

Tags: git, github, npm, installation

I am using [Angular 2 Google Maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) in my project. Someone created a branch that has the functionality I need. I would like to `npm i` that branch instead of master. I found a question telling me how to do it here ([Install specific branch from github using Npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732397/install-specific-branch-from-github-using-npm)), which recommends the following format:

```
npm install git://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader.git#v1 --save
```

So I tried:

```
npm i git://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps.git#add-clustered-markers --save
npm i git://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps.git#inovex:add-clustered-markers --save
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 add-clustered-markers
npm ERR! fatal: ambiguous argument 'add-clustered-markers': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
npm ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
npm ERR! 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) don't seem to cover installing branches. From the error, it seems that I need to specify the revision number somehow, I can't find information on how to do that.

TL;DR: How do I `npm i` a specific repo branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because that branch does not exist in the specified project.

[image]

Comment: The branch you are looking for is [https://github.com/jigfox/angular-google-maps/tree/add-clustered-markers](https://github.com/jigfox/angular-google-maps/tree/add-clustered-markers). The branch is in pull request on the main project.

Comment: Thanks, `npm i git://github.com/jigfox/angular-google-maps.git#add-clustered-markers --save` worked.