# How to load a feature branch from forked GitHub repo into my application?

Tags: git, github, npm

This feels like a question a person shouldn't have to ask, but I've been searching for the past 3 hours how to do this and I can't figure it out.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

1) fork a library from a GitHub repo, let's call it `vue-widget`

2) I need to get the files on my local machine somehow, most documentation says to do `git clone https://www.github.com/username/vue-widget.git`

My problems immediately begin around here because I don't know how to load the library into my project. I am trying to do:

```
import Widget from '@username/vue-widget';
```

The part that is making me quite frustrated is that all the help documentation I can find is written as if I am doing a 1 character change and then submitting a pull request, but I am doing a potentially extensive modification, so I need to run the modified feature branch in my application. **I can't find how to do that.**

I found some documentation from NPM that indicates I might be able to use scoped packages, but I can't figure out if that's required. Do I really need to fork a project and then publish it under my own name on NPM? or is there a faster, easier way?

I also understand I may be able to include a hash in the import, like:

```
import Widget from '@username/vue-widget#ose847vg6seo5489ve4e45n';
```

I am super lost about how to import `Widget` from a feature branch in my forked repo. I want to know what the most common and idiomatic way of doing this is.

My expectation is that there is a way I can clone my forked repo, create a feature branch, load that into my application, modify it, and then submit a pull request when it is ready.

> [edit]: My problem was that the library I was forking had the `/dist` folder in the .gitignore file, so my installation was not able to initialize properly due to those files not being built.

The solution is to remove `/dist` from the .gitignore file, then run:

```
npm run build
git add .
git commit -m "removed /dist from gitignore"
git push origin featureA
```

Then after that, back in the project you are trying to get the forked library into, do the solution that Max showed. In my case, I added this to my `package.json` file and then ran `npm install`:

```
"vue-widget": "username/vue-widget#featureA"
```

Here are some useful links that took me a while to uncover:

[How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

[npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

This is the one that actually solved it for me:

[npm install and build of forked github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528053/npm-install-and-build-of-forked-github-repo)

Be sure to read the comments below as there are a couple nice URLs about `npm link` that can be situationally useful.

Comment: Do you want to use the package's branch in your project in production or do you just want to work with the branch locally?

Comment: not in production, but I imagine that would require a public NPM scoped solution.

I want to know where I should clone the repo to, and then how to import it in so that it imports my feature branch.

Comment: So you can install branches of packages. It is explained in the link at the end here. Or I can explain what `npm link` is. Look and let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732397/install-specific-branch-from-github-using-npm

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: Thanks, that is a helpful set of links. I tried that earlier and it throws `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-widget'` after I do `npm run watch` to run the project. It added this to the package.json: `"vue-widget": "github:username/vue-widget#featureA"`.

Comment: So it's some kind of namespace issue or something. My forked repo isn't published on NPM. I don't know if that's related. I have to read more about linking. That may be the trick.

Comment: ok so if you just want to work with a forked repo locally, I can outline that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can install from a forked repo, you can do that following below

```
npm install --save git+https://git@github.com/[username]/[package name].git
```

If you need to link a module locally you can do the following. Use npm link. [The docs are here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

1. Go into the project you are working on locally and `npm i --save` the module you want to use from the npm registry.
2. Now, locally, clone the forked repo you want. Don't forget to `npm i` that module's dependencies.
3. In that forked directory run `npm link`. This should take those forked files and link them to the local reference. Any time you have a change or switch branches in this local module you want to see in another local project, you have to run `npm link`.
4. Now go to the project you are working on locally and run `npm link [module you forked and cloned locally]`
5. Restart your project and you should see the changes.

`npm link` can be a little finicky, but when you run step 4, you should see the file path to your locally link files.

Comment: With that and after doing `link`, it shows `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-widget'`. It seems to have a hard time when the dependency name is the same as the regular package from the maintainers. It didn't put anything in my node_modules folder after running that npm install.

Comment: @agm1984 You don't have to do link since you are sourcing the modules from github. You might be messing up with namespace by linking

Comment: I just typed `npm link` trying to get a list of links, naive attempt, and what it actually did was add `vue-widget` into my node_modules folder, but same error output.

Comment: I don't understand how it could be so brutally difficult to load a forked version. There must be something fandamental I am missing. Is this wrong? `import Widget from 'vue-widget';`Is there any way I can just tell it to forget NPM and do like `import Widget from '../vue-widget'`. That way the project wouldn't have to care what branch it's loading. It would just load whatever branch is currently selected.

Comment: The problem to me with an idea like that is the package would be outside the root of the project, which is usually a bad idea, and if it was inside the project, it will wreak havoc on my local git file management

Comment: My desired steps are simple: 1) fork a library, 2) clone it locally, 3) checkout a new branch, 4) edit some file to cause a visible change, 5) import that into my project, 6) run the project, 7) observe the changed file. That is proving very difficult and complex.

Comment: Max, can I clone the forked repo into my node_modules folder? I found a tutorial by Kent Dodds on egghead.io that shows something like that and then doing `npm install`. That looks like something that might work

Comment: @agm1984. You have to be able to install the module into your project because when your project is running and you call `import` or `require` your app is going to look into your node modules for that module. Locally, you can `npm link` to tell your app to look at local files rather than what is in your node modules, but you still need that reference in your package json

Comment: Thanks for your help Max. It turns out that the library I am forking had `/dist` folder in the .gitignore file, so no matter how I pulled the fork in, it wasn't working. It wasn't able to resolve the package because it wasn't installed correctly. I recall it's a common issue, but it took a while to figure out. Your answer is definitely correct overall.