# import node module on react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, query-builder, antd

I installed [react-awesome-query-builder](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/tree/antd-3) from branch `antd-3` but after import on react file, there is an error that says:

> import {Query, Builder, Utils as QbUtils} from 'react-awesome-query-builder';
>
> Error :
>
> Failed to compile ./src/shared/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-awesome-query-builder' in 'D:\manshoor_ui\src\shared\queryBuilder'

This module is added to `package.json` and `node_modules` but there is this error. I installed by this command:

```
npm install --save ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder#antd-3
```

So what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

According to [github docs](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder) documentation for that package, it's supposed to be installed like this:

`npm i react-awesome-query-builder`

And then you import it like this:

`import {Query, Builder, Utils} from 'react-awesome-query-builder';`

Comment: This is does not answer the question. OP wants a __custom branch__

Comment: OP didn't say anything about that, but if that is wanted, found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732501/4083414) for installing a package from github (which allows also specifing branches)