# Using a local NPM package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to use a NPM package which i downloaded from GitHub, but having no luck.

I created a `lib` folder in my src directory of my create-react-app project.

Then i used wget to download the tarball

```
wget https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-image-lightbox/tarball/master/master.tar.gz
```

I then changed the name of the tarball

```
mv master.tar.gz react-image-lightbox-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

Then I installed the package using NPM

```
npm install ./src/lib/react-image-lightbox-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

In my package.json it shows;

```
"react-image-lightbox": "file:src/lib/react-image-lightbox-5.2.0.tar.gz",
```

So that all worked nicely.

But when i try and import the package using;

```js
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';
```

i get the following error message when doing a `npm run build`

```
Cannot find module: 'react-image-lightbox'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install react-image-lightbox.
```

Im missing something but I cant figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason for downloading the source instead of installing via `npm`? - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox

Comment: @SungM.Kim ... Yes, there is a bugfix which has been pulled into the master, but not into the NPM build

Comment: That's a good reason for sure. I've seen people using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to apply fixes in their NPM packages. But as I haven't used it, I won't be able to add it as an answer.

Comment: It might just not be resolving the local file properly, from memory the last time I used a local package I didn't use the "file:" prefix but instead gave the full location from the root directory, like "react-image-lightbox": "/Users/<user>/projects/<project>/src/lib/react-image-lightbox-5.2.0.tar.gz" and after installing all deps I could confirm it's there by checking the node_modules folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to get the code from GitHub you want manually by using `wget` and `mv`.

You can install the master version of the repository by using its Git clone URL:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-image-lightbox.git
```

The resulting `package.json` file will look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-image-lightbox": "git+https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-image-lightbox.git"
  }
}
```

You can then use the package like you would use the regular one:

```
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';
```

Comment: What if i want to use different branch other than master

Comment: add the branch name to the URL separated by a pound sign, see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732397/install-specific-branch-from-github-using-npm