# How do you install a repo by branch name in a github enterprise repo?

Tags: npm, branch, git-branch

I would like to install repos to a parent repo and specify by branch name.
I have tried the following:

```
npm install username/repo#branchName --save
npm install username/repo@branchName --save
npm install username/repo#tag --save
npm install username/repo@tag --save
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
Could not install from {theRepoWithBranch} as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

The repo definitely contains a package.json file. 
I'm wondering if this is a permissions issue given I'm using an enterprise npm registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[npm/npm issue 19788](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19788#issue-296088973) does mention:

> Currently, `npm` **does not support installation of modules from git services hosted on private domain names**.
>   That includes both Github for Enterprise on custom domains as well as instances of gitlab, gitea, gogs, bitbucket and many others, basically anything hosted on a custom domain name.

With the comment:

> So, obviously you reference installing via an http(s):// URL directly, but just as an fyi, our GitLab Enterprise instance allows us to install using a slightly different format.
>   We have 2FA enabled, so it requires SSH to be used.
>   From the docs.
>
> ```
> npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
> npm install <git repo url>
> ```
>
> We were able to actually install our repos like this:
>
> ```
> npm install git+ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:user/repo.git
> ```

So this is more a URL format combined with permission issue.
Regarding the branch, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732501/6309), your syntax is correct.

And:

> if I prepend git+ on the HTTPS URL it works (I run gitea which accepts basic auth)

See also [`npm/hosted-git-info` PR 30](https://github.com/npm/hosted-git-info/pull/30#issuecomment-400074956)

Comment: Hmmm...for some reason when it is installed there is no lib or dist directories. The node_modules are also included. For any other install the node_modules are not included and there are lib and dist directories...Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: @zero_cool Not on the top of my head. It would be interesting to explore that particular case in a separate question, highlighting the differences between that incomplete module, and others which do install properly.

Comment: I figured it out :) You add a "prepare" script to your package.json that handles the build. It looks like prepare gets run on npm i if it exists. We use builder for builds so the script that worked for me was what works locally. I imagine that whatever works for you locally would work in that script.