# Rollup obfuscator plugin not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollup

I have this config:

```
import ts from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import { uglify } from "rollup-plugin-uglify";
import obfuscator from "rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/bundle.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
    {
      file: "dist/ugly-bundle.js",
      format: "cjs",
      plugins: [uglify()],
    },
    {
      file: "dist/obfuscate-bundle.js",
      format: "cjs",
      plugins: [obfuscator({ compact: true })],
    },
  ],
  plugins: [ts()],
};
```

And am trying to obfuscate a my files. The problem is, All other plugins work, but obfuscator doesn't. And I have no clue why. I tried removing the `{compact}` options, but no difference. It just transpiles the code, so the `obfuscate-bundle.js` is the same as `bundle.js`. `ugly-bundle.js` is in one line, and minified.

What am I missing?

I'm using this package: https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin is outdated, rollup change their function names, [see this change](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator/pull/8/files#diff-bfe9874d239014961b1ae4e89875a6155667db834a410aaaa2ebe3cf89820556)

> The "transformBundle" hook used by plugin javascript-obfuscator is
> deprecated. The "renderChunk" hook should be used instead.

You should use another plugin: [`rollup-plugin-obfuscator`](https://github.com/getkey/rollup-plugin-obfuscator)

```sh
yarn add --dev rollup-plugin-obfuscator javascript-obfuscator
# or
npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-obfuscator javascript-obfuscator
```

### Old answer

And for install I suggest use git [repo with custom name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627279/10722053):

```sh
npm install rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator@scarletsky/rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator
//or
yarn add rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator@scarletsky/rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator
```

In this case you can look on [network graph](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/rollup-plugin-javascript-obfuscator/network) and try find better replacement

Comment: Ah ok. So I'd have to write my own? All other plugins use this one

Comment: You might have more luck with https://github.com/getkey/rollup-plugin-obfuscator (I'm its author, I've been maintaining it for 3 years)