# How To Update Git Hash in npm package.json git project?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

How do I specify exact git hash in `package.json` dependencies for a Github project, and have an easy way to upgrade it at the same time?

My `package.json` is as follow:

```
{
  "name": "my faboulous app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "request": "request/request#5ee89063cd"
  }
}
```

It relies on a Github project: https://github.com/request/request and uses specific revision which is `5ee89063cd`.

I want to stick to specific version, so when someones clones my project and calls `npm install` she has the same `request` dependency version as me.

But at certain point in time, there comes an important bugfix for me, and I want to upgrade the `revision` in `package.json` to the newest version that is available at Github.

Is it possible to achieve this with `npm update` command? How can I upgrade the revision from command line, instead of manually editing the file?

My understanding is that, when I call `npm install` it always takes the hash that is specified in `package.json`. But when I call `npm update` I would like to have `package.json` `request` dependency updated to the latest repository version of it with the newest revision hash.

How can I achieve that? If not with `npm update` maybe there is the other simple way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install from Git in a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187956/npm-install-from-git-in-a-specific-version)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Checkout the [git-npm-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-npm-updater) package which can get the job done for you.

`git-npm-updater` automatically updates npm dependencies presented in your package.json and create pull requests to your git repo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems it doesn't work for github project, only for semver projects

Comment: Ah!. How did I miss that?! Please check my updated post above and see if it is helpful.