# NPM install/update: Getting the latest version without having to alter package.json with Git repository

Tags: git, npm, dependencies, versioning, package.json

The dependencies in my package.json look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "shared-styleguide": "git+https://oauth2:key@my.company.at/project/shared-styleguide#master",
    "handlebars": "github:wycats/handlebars.js",
    "underscore": "^1.9.2"
  }
```

There are constantly changes to the "shared styleguide" package. Whenever I do `npm i` or `npm update` the shared styleguide package is not updated. I have to remove the `#master` and do npm update (nothing happens) and then I have to add the `#master` in the end and do `npm update` again to finally get the latest version. This is a also a problem for the deployment workflow as it seems like cached old versions of the styleguide library are used sometimes.

How can I write this into my package.json to get always the latest version of the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an acceptable - still not good workaround: Specify the commit hash within the package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "shared-styleguide": "git+https://oauth2:key@my.company.at/project/shared-styleguide#bf6947b3a4c4334072c6dd96bd61b0893d1cb69c",
    "handlebars": "github:wycats/handlebars.js",
    "underscore": "^1.9.2"
  }
```

More Info:

[What are commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git)

[npm install from Git in a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187956/npm-install-from-git-in-a-specific-version/18049685#18049685)

Better solutions are still welcome.