# How can I target a git #branch@version with npm?

Tags: npm

I have a fork in github.  I am able to install target like this in npm

`"my-fork-of-a-package": "github:my-profile/my-fork-of-a-package#branch"`

in package.json.  However I am unable to target a tag of the branch or a version number.

I'm looking for a some kind of @version or @tag or @commitHash syntax.
Something kinda like this - except for that this doesn't work.
`'"my-fork-of-a-package": "github:my-profile/my-fork-of-a-package#branch@version"`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14188105/2614364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the `#semver:<semver>` notation like so:

```
"my-fork-of-a-package": "github:my-profile/my-fork-of-a-package#semver:v1.0.27"
```

- see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/install

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tricky for a potential answer because **generally, a branch implies the version number.**

As per docs:

```
npm install gitlab:<gitlabname>/<gitlabrepo>[#<commit-ish>]:
```

> Install the package at https://gitlab.com/gitlabname/gitlabrepo by
>   attempting to clone it using git.
>
> If # is provided, it will be used to clone exactly that
>   commit.  If the commit-ish has the format #semver:,  
>   can be any valid semver range or **exact version**
>
> > https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Why don't you simply consolidate on only one level (branch1-v1, branch1-v2,branch2-v1...)?

You can effectively call a #branch, so i think it would be safe for you to rename & update your data structure to be 1 big pool with specific names.

That way, you'll be able to call the specific package/git through #branch1{your-own-separator}version-X.X

TL;DR:
Add tags in name, will look messy but that's why search/indexes exist.

Comment: This may not be a good example with gitlab, as gitlab appears to me not to allow for cloning, even public, versions of a particular branch. When I imported a repo to github, and then npm'd, it worked.